# Call function using more than one variable. PHP - Laravel - Blade

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I'm trying to call one function (get the week day(is working)) that I've made on Controller e needed two variables.
But when I call from the view (using Blade from Laravel) I got the message that I'm passing only one atribute, instead two.

My control:

```
public function getWeekDay($monthYear, $qtdDay){ 

    $month = substr($monthYear, 0, 2);
    $year= substr($monthYear, 3, 4);
    $month = $month + 1;

    $lastDay = date('m/d/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 0, $year));

    $firstDay = strtotime($lastDay . ' +'.$qtdDay.' Weekday');

   return date('d/m/Y', $firstDay);
}
```

My view:

```
{!! app(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Site\\TarefaController::class)->getWeekDay( [$monthYear , $qtdDay ) }}
```

Is it the way that I should call function from Blade??

Comment: Where is th closing `]`? And why you use `[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `function` as static.

```
public static function getWeekDay($monthYear, $qtdDay){ //** static

    $month = substr($monthYear, 0, 2);
    $year= substr($monthYear, 3, 4);
    $month = $month + 1;

    $lastDay = date('m/d/Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 0, $year));

    $firstDay = strtotime($lastDay . ' +'.$qtdDay.' Weekday');

   return date('d/m/Y', $firstDay);
}
```

In your `view` call

```
{{ \App\Http\Controllers\Site\TarefaController::getWeekDay($monthYear, $qtdDay) }}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I changed the view and controller, but still not working. I got the message: Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Site\TarefaController::getWeekDay(), 1 passed (view with error) and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Are $monthYear, $qtdDay both have values when you pass them in view?

Comment: Yes, actually I'm using the same variable that I'm using to make the table.

Comment: Try {{ dd($monthYear) }} and {{ dd($qtdDay) }}  inside view above that call and see what values.

Comment: {{ dd($monthYear) }} I've got "06/2016" , and {{ dd($qtdDay) }} I've got "2"

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the parameters as one **array** now

```
{!! app(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Site\\TarefaController::class)->getWeekDay( [$monthYear , $qtdDay ) }}
```

Change into

```
{!! app(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Site\\TarefaController::class)->getWeekDay( $monthYear , $qtdDay ) }}
```

Comment: I removed the [, it was wrong.. but still not working!!